# Add quote in existing regex Java

Tags: java, regex

I have this existing regex : `^[_A-Za-z0-9-+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*`

I want to add a quote in this regex. It can be anywhere and it must be present zero or only one time.

I haven't found what I need to add to be able to do this. Someone has an idea ?

Comment: Can you post some examples of valid and invalid strings?

Comment: provide an example of input and expected result

Comment: Assert the presence of only a single `'` and add it to both character classes `^(?=[^']*'[^']*$)[_A-Za-z0-9-+']+(\.[_A-Za-z0-9-']+)*$`  https://regex101.com/r/dJCD44/1

Comment: your regex can simplfy to this: `^[\w-+]+(\\.[\w-]+)*`

Comment: some example : 

aaa'aa.bbbb
aaaaa.bb'bb
aaaa'.bbbbb
aaaa.'bbbbb

Comment: @JeromeF99 and what is the expected result?

Comment: I want zero or only one time quote

Comment: @Thefourthbird It matches but does not take into account the fact that there may be zero quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add the `'` to both character classes and start the pattern with a positive lookahead assertion for the presence of an optional `'` anywhere in the string by making what is before and after the `'` optional in the lookahead.

```
^(?=[\w.+-]*(?:'[\w.-]+)?$)[\w+'-]+(?:\.[\w-']+)*$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert what is on the right is

  - `[\w.+-]*` Match 0+ times any of `[\w.+-]*`
  - `(?:'[\w.-]+)?$` Optionally match `'` and 0+ times any of `[\w.-]` and assert the end of the string.
- `)` Close the lookahead
- `[\w+'-]+` Match 1+ word chars `'` or `-`
- `(?:\.[\w-']+)*` Optionally repeat matching the previous preceded by a `.`
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LAUDaF/1)

In Java

```
String regex = "^(?=[\\w.+-]*(?:'[\\w.-]+)?$)[\\w+'-]+(?:\\.[\\w-']+)*$";
```

Comment: In reality my regex is ^[_A-Za-z0-9-+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9-]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z0-9-]{2,30})$ and i would like to add quote only before @

What should I add to what you just sent?

Comment: @JeromeF99 Then it could be like this `^(?=[\\w.+-]*(?:'[\\w.-]+)?@)[_A-Za-z0-9-+']+(\\.[\\w-']+)*@[\\w-]+(?:\\.[\\w-]+)*(?:\\.[\\w-]{2,30})$` See  https://regex101.com/r/rUrYpD/1

Comment: it's almost perfect but it doesn't work for that : a.b'@test.com

Comment: @JeromeF99 I see, now it will work. https://regex101.com/r/ahYnqB/1